# heroku not updating database schema

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, schema, migration, heroku

Heroku doesn't seem to update my database schema when I deploy. Here are the details:

Here is what is should look like for the User class:

```
create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
t.string   "username"
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
t.string   "email"
t.string   "encrypted_password"
t.string   "salt"
t.string   "remember_token"
t.boolean  "admin",              :default => false
```

end

Here is my deploy procedure:

```
git push heroku master
heroku rake db:migrate
heroku db:push
```

Everything seems to go smoothly... except that if I check the actually User table in db...

```
heroku console User
```

... I get an old version of User...

```
User(id: integer, username: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?
Thanks a lot for your help!

Simon

Comment: Are you sure that all your migrations are under source control?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Do you see any output when you `heroku rake db:migrate`?

Try running `heroku restart` after you migrate to restart the web servers and DJ workers. That shouldn't influence your console, but I have seen web servers serving old versions of the code immediately after a deploy, which normally isn't a problem but with pending migrations can be.

Comment: Thanks tfe, it seems it was a temporary problem. It is working just fine now. I guess a restart would have solve the problem too.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try

> heroku run rake db:migrate 
>   heroku restart

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is right. FYI though, you now use `heroku run rake db:migrate` because `heroku rake db:migrate` is deprecated

Answer (score -1):

Run `heroku rake run db:migrate`
Then `heroku restart`

Refresh your web page and it should all work.